# PHP : Undefined Index Errors while building Search with filter

Tags: php, search, filter

//Error: information gets appended but not replaced.

```
<form action="testme.php" method="get">
    <p>
        <input name="search" type="text" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    </p>

    <h3>Filter Results</h3>
<p><a href="testme.php?filter='Action'<?php if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {echo '&search='.$_GET['search'];}
?>">Action</a></p>


<p><a href="testme.php?filter='Comedy'<?php if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {echo '&search='.$_GET['search'];}
?>">Comedy</a></p>

</form>


<?php

if (isset($_GET['button']) && isset($_GET['search']) != '') {
    echo $_GET['search'];

}
elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && isset($_GET['search']) != '') {
    echo "Action " . $_GET['search'];

}

elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && isset($_GET['search']) == '') {

    echo " No action Involved ";
}

if (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Comedy" && isset($_GET['search']) == '') {

    echo " No Comedy Involved";
}
```

//when I click either of link I get: No action Involved No comedy Involved. But I only want one to show
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

its because of the `$_GET['search']` is undifined

the correct code :

```
 <form action="index.php" method="get">
    <p>
        <input name="search" type="text" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    </p>



    <h3>Filter Results</h3>
    <p>
    <a href="index.php?filter='Action'&search=<?php if (isset($_GET['search'])) { echo $_GET['search']; } ?>">Action</a>
    </p>
</form>


    <?php

if (isset($_GET['button']) && isset($_GET['search']) != '') {
    echo $_GET['search'];

}
elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && isset($_GET['search']) != '') {
    echo "Action " . $_GET['search'];

}
//the logic is to click on the action without filling in the search form and get it to work

elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && empty($_GET['search'])) {

    echo "No action Involved";
}
?>
```

Comment: It works. But I get the first second condition also running. So the output is "Action No Action Involved"; I only want to output "No Action Involved"

Comment: <a href="index.php?filter='Action'<?php if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) { echo '&search='.$_GET['search']; } ?>">Action</a>

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, not after that.  So when the page is first sent, the code for building your link has no value yet.

Answer (score 0):

you must have before defined GET['search'] and then to declare this  `<a href="index.php?filter='Action'&search=<?php echo $_GET['search']`

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
<a href="index.php?filter='Action'&search=<?=@$_GET['search']; ?>>
```

Comment: the code works but the output is "Action No action involved" instead of "No Action Involved"

Comment: replace this: `elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && isset($_GET['search']) != '') {
    echo "Action " . $_GET['search'];

}` with this

Comment: elseif (isset($_GET['filter']) == "Action" && isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {
    echo "Action " . $_GET['search'];

}

Comment: Thanks a lot man: Is it ok to use this also:<a href="index.php?filter='Action'<?php if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) { echo '&search='.$_GET['search']; } ?>">Action</a>